# Add an "Email" view in a Control Form with an Outlook VSTO

Tags: c#, outlook, ms-office, vsto

I'm developping an Outlook VSTO that transform email content.

So far, I'm able to arbitrary change the content of the email view using an Outlook Form :

[image: screenshot]

Is it possible to add a programatically generated `MailItem` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mailitem?view=outlook-pia) like:

```
Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem) this.Application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
mailItem.Subject = "This is the subject";
mailItem.To = "someone@example.com";
mailItem.Body = "This is the message.";
```

And to "design" it to have something like that :

[image: screenshot]

I did not find any "Email" component in the toolbox. Is there any built-in UI widget in Outlook VSTO library that enable a VSTO to do this ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to have your custom UI (Form Region) visible only for certain emails?

Comment: No, I already have a "Custom UI" visible for certain emails.
I would like to add an arbitrary MailItem "email view" within this custom UI.

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific component or control that includes the full header of an email.  However, you can approximate that design using any of the Outlook Controls, such as the Outlook Contact Photo Control, Date Control, Recipient Control, etc.  See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb206789(v=office.12).

Comment: Thanks but those controls does not seems to axist anymore in modern Office Library :-/ (I hope I'm wrong)

Comment: You have to set a COM reference to Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.Forms and add them to the Visual Studio Toolbox manually

Comment: Only "Microsoft Outlook View/Body/Recipient Control" seem to be available in my environement, and they does not work properly ("Unable to create AxHost component").

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what's going on there

Comment: It's ok, thanks anyway for provided efforts, it was very helpful !